# How to print whole array in tcsh

Tags: unix, csh, tcsh

I want to print the whole array in tcsh, because then i want to pipe it to uniq, is there a way to do it in tcsh.

i had `set array`

and was printing it:

```
echo "$array"
```

but it ended up with error: Word too long, it works for smaller arrrays,

Is there some simple way to do it?

Comment: Perhaps tcsh isn't the best tool for what you're doing.

Comment: Also posted on Unix&Linux [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99292/10454).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution to this problem is to work with files instead of variables:

```
cat > file <<EOF
YOUR ARRAY TEXT HERE.....
EOF
uniq file
```